# Fundamental theorem of Galois covers

Tags: algebraic-topology

I attempted the proof in Tamas Szamuely's book, *Galois groups and fundamental groups*. I am stuck in the last portion.

The cover $q \colon Z \to X$ is Galois if and only if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, in which case $\operatorname{Aut(Z\mid X)} \cong G/H$.

I am not able to prove this part. Please suggest some hints and explanation for the above. Thanks.

Comment: Are $G$ and $H$ fundamental groups?

Comment: p:Y→X is a covering map G= Aut(Y∣X) and H<G